# Select all content in div when clicked?/Resize textbox to fit text?

Tags: css, select, html, width

I've been searching around now for a while and I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

I'm making a little box, which has the width of the text inside it that, when clicked, selects all text. Much like a textbox with "onclick='this.select();'" but I want it to have the size of whatever size the text inside it has, like a div with "float:left;".

So, is there a way to make a div select all of it's content when clicked, or is there a way to make a textbox have exactly the width of it's preset "value".

(I also would like to find a solution without extra plugins, for example jQuery.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

HTML:

```
<div class="select" >Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah.......</div>
```

CSS:

```
.select
 {
  border: medium solid;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
 -webkit-touch-callout: all;
 -webkit-user-select: all;
 -khtml-user-select: all;
 -moz-user-select: all;
 -ms-user-select: all;
 }
```

Demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/RQ62f/28/)